# I want to completely replace Ubuntu with Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, lubuntu

I accidentally issued some commands I thought were safe in the terminal, and I ended up with no *System Settings* and lots of other missing functionality, but the OS still boots normally. I've decided I want to install Lubuntu instead of fixing Ubuntu for a fresh start and since my laptop is running on a 1GHz dual core AMD CPU.

I created a bootable USB as I usually do and placed Lubuntu 17.10 amd64 using Rufus 2.14.1086. I have GRUB that was installed with Ubuntu upon first install I still have Win8.1 which I still want to keep.

PS: I also tried creating a startup disk from Ubuntu

The question is: How can I boot from USB with GRUB2 so I can overwrite Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you [**try** the Lubuntu 18.04 LTS iso file](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389) **`lubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386.iso`**, and if it works in your computer, it is a better choice, because it has support for **3 years** from now.

Lubuntu 17.10 has support for only 3 more **months**.

---

- Backup your personal data (files, that you want to keep) to another drive.
- When you boot from Lubuntu and start the installer, at the partitioning window, you can select **Something else** and select the partition, where you have Windows to re-use it (and install alongside Windows).
- The installer should install the grub bootloader and find Windows for you automatically. If Windows is hibernated or semi-hibernated (alias fast startup), there are problems, so you should turn that off (in Windows).

Comment: Laptop is running on amd cpu isn't the i386 for intel cpus?

Comment: Also i changed to UEFI in BIOS and i was able to boot and now installing the OS and hopefully everything goes right.  Lubuntu warned me that other OSs available are using BIOS compatibility mode and using UEFI won't boot to other systems or something like that

Comment: There is an old convention, that i386 represents a 32-bit kernel and amd64 represents a 64-bit kernel. This works in PC computers with Intel and AMD processors. But **i386** systems work only in BIOS mode, so in UEFI mode you need an **amd64** iso file. - It will be more convenient to switch between the operating systems, if you install and boot both of them in the same mode (both in UEFI or both in BIOS mode).